# net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED (file:///data/user/0/packagename/files/appname/app_id/idex.html) in android

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, permissions, access-denied

We have updated android target version from 29 to 30 due to play store app publish issue. From our android app  We are trying to load in a html file in web view.at the time we are facing below issue.

> net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED (file:///data/user/0/packagename/files/appname/app_id/idex.html)

at the same time I reverted back the target version to 29. It was working fine and html was loading properly.

Comment: Probably you should set a flag in webviewclient to allow source locally.

Comment: are you supporting [Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage)?

Comment: Try to your code i have received same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can add these for the webview and try.

```
webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
```

Comment: Try to your code i have received following same error.

DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for file:///data/data/com.chainsys.appContainer/files/Dyna_UI/139913/bootstrap.js.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND